# How to set an alias to a fields on a db_select?

Tags: entities, database

Like it said on the title, as we use alias to fields with a static query, i want to do same thing with a dynamic query

example :

with static select : `$sql = db_query ("SELECT my_super_long_field as mslf FROM {super_long_table} as slt")`

How to perform same with a db_select query please ?

```
$sql = db_select ('super_long_table','slt')
->fields('slt',array('mys_super_long_field', 'here i want alias for long fields')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `addField()`. Here's an example:

```
$query = db_select('super_long_table', 'slt');
$query->addField('slt', 'mys_super_long_field', 'mslf');
```

Arguments passed to `addField()` are:

- Table alias
- Field - your long field name will be here
- Alias - your short field alias will be here

Read more about it [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQueryInterface%3A%3AaddField/7).